# Mat-select tag in loop selecting last value as default value for all dropdowns

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have Mat-select tag which is in a loop with *ngFor and selecting last value as default for all dropdowns

```
<div *ngFor="let investment of data.priorInvestmentExperiences; >

      <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="mat-type">

        <mat-select [(ngModel)]="investment.productTypeCode"
                    formControlName="productTypeCode"
                    class="form-control">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let type of InvestmentTypes "
                      value="{{type.code}}">
            {{type.name}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
        <mat-label><strong> Investment Type </strong> </mat-label>
        <mat-error *ngIf="f.productTypeCode.errors?.required">
          Investment Type is <strong>required</strong>
        </mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
```

How to get different default value  for all dropdowns in Loop?
 please help me to find the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried the above code in stackblitz (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zhbe9o?file=app%2Fselect-overview-example.html). I can able to set different options for different select. Not sure what exactly your problem. I can think of one reason why may your code not work

Even through you create select control in ngFor loop you attached same formcontrol for all select. So it will bind Same default value to all select control.

Also don't use formcontrol and ngmodel together. formcontrol replacement for ngModel. Check the below code see if it's solve the problem. If not create some sample with the error scenrio will try to solve that

```html
<div *ngFor="let investment of data.priorInvestmentExperiences">
    <mat-form-field appearance=" outline " class="mat-type ">
        <mat-label><strong> Investment Type </strong> </mat-label>
        <mat-select [(value)]="investment.productTypeCode">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let type of InvestmentTypes" [value]=type.code>
                {{type.name}}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
        <mat-error >
          Investment Type is <strong>required</strong>
        </mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
      </div>
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'select-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'select-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['select-overview-example.css'],
})
export class SelectOverviewExample {
  InvestmentTypes = [{
    code: 1, name: 'invesmentType1'
  }, {
    code: 2, name: 'invesmentType2'
  }, {
    code: 3, name: 'invesmentType3'
  }, {
    code: 4, name: 'invesmentType4'
  }]
  data = {
    priorInvestmentExperiences: [{
      productTypeCode: 1
    }, {
      productTypeCode: 2
    }, {
      productTypeCode: 3
    }, {
      productTypeCode: 4
    }]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ravin. I understand that i have used same formcontrol for all select in loop. And its working without formcontrol and with [(value)]  for mat-select. But is there any way that i can use formcontrol for this mat-select and it should be different for all select?

Comment: Watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0mbFyp0AmUM&list=PLOETEcp3DkCrmGI9bHXMDsxl6_YdnZr7M&index=58. Might solve your problem